# Problem installing Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node.js on a linux machine but i get this error when i run "make":

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/bin/node/node-v0.2.6/build' 
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cc ares_strcasecmp.c -> ares_strcasecmp_1.o} 
make: *** [all] Fel 1
```

This is what i've done:

```
tar zxf node-v0.2.6.tar.gz
cd node-v0.2.6
./configure --jobs=1 --prefix=$HOME
make
```

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing again with the [official instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation). Alternatively, try one of [these methods](http://gist.github.com/579814) after you're *sure you have all the dependencies installed*.

Remember to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.